# Disable GridViewColumn Resize

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, gridviewcolumn

Is there any way by which I can disable GridViewColumn resize in WPF? I don't want to style the control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this link: [Fixed-Width Column in ListView: A Column that cannot be resized](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/04/11/573037.aspx)

> A fixed-width column is a column that cannot be resized by mouse
>   dragging or double-clicks. You can find instances in outlook.
>   Currently two methods can be used to achieve the effect. One is to
>   restyle GridViewColumnHeader to remove the gripper inside its
>   Template. The other is to subclass GridViewColumn to restrict columns'
>   width to a fixed size.

Answer (score -4):

Could you explain me in detail and please give me your code.

If you want to disable the column of a GridView , you can use

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

then column 0 of the grid become disable and the other column of the grid resize automatically.

Comment: Visible is NOT a property of a GridViewColumn.

Comment: Visible is NOT a property of a GridViewColumn. thus this solution doesn't work and is incorrect!